# Activate Macro when Cell is Clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to finish this off so that I can click on cells ws2(D11) and ws3(C12) and show a box containing the ClientNumber. I just can't get my head around how that works, as I've tried to adapt some solutions to my code, but have been unsuccessful, and don't know quite why.

```
Public ClientNumber As String


Sub Booker()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("ClientEnd")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Booking End")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Training End")

Dim ClientName As String


ClientName = InputBox("Please enter your name")

ClientNumber = InputBox("Please enter a contact number")

ws2.Range("D11") = ClientName

ws3.Range("C12") = ClientName

ws2.Range("O11:R11").Style = "Good"

ws3.Range("H12:K12").Style = "Good"

ws3.Range("I12").Style = "Normal"

Call NumberBox

End Sub


Sub NumberBox()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("ClientEnd")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Booking End")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Training End")

If Target.Address = ws2.Range("$D$11") Then MsgBox ClientNumber
If Target.Address = ws3.Range("$C$12") Then MsgBox ClientNumber

End Sub
```

I was hoping to have the ClientNumber pop up in a message when I clicked on the given cells in each sheet, which do update to the ClientName successfully, but nothing happens. No errors, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)`.

In ws3 put

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C12")) Is Nothing Then 'range than u want to capture       
        Call NumberBox 'your code
    End If
End Sub
```

Do the same for ws2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11")) Is Nothing Then 'range than u want to capture       
        Call NumberBox 'your code
    End If
End Sub
```

You have to double click on the cell to run the event

Comment: That's pretty much perfect. The number still isn't pulling through properly but I can probably sort that myself, many thanks!

Comment: i think u have to send the ClientNumber to the function NumberBox().change Call NumberBox to Call NumberBox (ClientNumber ) and Sub NumberBox() to Sub NumberBox(ClientNumber as string). good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the SelectionChange event to the worksheets. On Worksheet 2 and 3 Add the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "&D&11" Then 'Change the "&D&11" to "&C&12" for worksheet 3
        Call NumberBox ' You could also add Target as a paramater
    End If
End Sub
```